# Can you use RoboBrowser's get.form without Class, Action, or Id tags

Tags: python, python-3.x, robobrowser

```
  <form data-bind="submit: login">
   <!-- UserName -->
    <div class="form-group">
     <label>Username</label>
     <input class="form-control" type="text" data-bind="value: username" name="username" tabindex="1" />
    </div>
    <!-- Password -->
     <div class="form-group">
      <label>Password</label> <a class="ajax-link" tabindex="4" href="/unauth/#/forgot" data-bind="if: EmailConfirmationRequired">(forgot password)</a>
      <input class="form-control" type="password" id="UserDto_Password" data-bind="value: password" name="password" tabindex="2" />
     </div>
    <!-- Submit-->
    <button tabindex="3" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" type="submit">Sign in</button>
      <span class="spinner22" data-bind="visible: showSpinner"></span>
      <span class="error-label" data-bind="visible: result().length > 0, text: result" style="display: none; padding-left: 9px;">
     </span>
  </form>
```

I've seen multiple examples on how to use `RoboBrowser` to get the form on websites. The website I am trying to log into however does not have anything resembling the examples I have seen. I know every website is different but most have at least one of the three tags like `class`, `ID`, or action near the beginning where the form code begins. I've tried some class tags that are inside the form code but when I print to check I get "None". There is `data-bind` but I am unsure how to use that.

Comment: If you are using chrome you can use xpath

Comment: Thank you that helped. I decided to use Selenium since it has more information on using xpath find commands.

Comment: Yeah, and selenium also has javascript support